# Uses of chien franks?

Tags: jagged-alliance-3

Are there any uses of chien franks in the game? So far I've only found exactly one NPC merchant accepting them in exchange for various parts, in Port Cacao. Are there any other uses of them or are they essentially just junk items?

EDIT: I also found a second NPC merchant in the poacher camp which similarly also accepts franks in trade for something. But thats the only uses I've found.